# Artifactory Sample Plugins: unable to invoke altRemotePath of download

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to write an Artifactory plugin which uses altRemotePath method of download

```
  download {
    altRemotePath { repoPath ->
        log.info "Original Path is =${ repoPath}"
    }
  }
```

On click of download button the script is not called at all and nothing comes in the log

Note: I am able to run other methods such as

```
       beforeDownloadRequest { request, repoPath ->
```

but not

```
       altRemotePath { repoPath ->
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `altRemotePath` callback is not being invoked because you're downloading an artifact that's already stored in Artifactory.

Reviewing Artifactory's [User Plugin documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins), we can see that the spec states that this callback is invoked:

> When reaching out to remote repositories

This means that the callback will only be invoked when executing a request that is expected to resolve an artifact from a remote repository.